# Wordpress CSV or Excel Import and Display Plug-in

Tags: wordpress, csv

I am looking for a general purpose or specialized Wordpress plug-in that would enable the following basic functionality.

1. Import a CSV file say 10 columns wide and up to a 1000 rows.
2. I would want the data stored in a database and not just as a HTML table in a post.
3. I would need a couple of key fields that could be referenced in a short code to imbed the contents into a post. Such as Wordpress Category, Tag, or Slug in combination with a date and product name.
4. I need a way to imbed a filtered data set based on the key fields into a post or page.
5. In Display it should be able to sort by a specified detail field.

Without doing a ERD chart this is approximately how I envision the data:

- Category/Tag/Slug: Used Repeatedly across individual rows and
  uploads.
- Product/Location/Event: Consistent to Category/Tag/Slug, but
  will appear multiple times.
- Date: Date of the data Detail Fields:
  Individual Detail fields (say 7) about the data entry.

Example data:

> - Car, Raceway Park, 01/25/2015, 77 Impala, Red, 03:02.22, 203, Chevy, Mike Goodfish
>
>   - Car, Raceway Park, 01/25/2015, 78 Ford Nova, Red, 03:01.22, 204, Nova, Kyle Goodfish
>   - Car, Raceway Park, 01/25/2015, 93 Chevy AstroVan, Blue, 01:01.22, 205, Chevy, Mic Rib
>   - Car, Raceway Park, 01/25/2015, 93 Escort, Blue, 02:37.22, 207, Ford, Molly George
>   - Car, Raceway Park, 01/27/2015, 77 Impala, Red, 03:20.22, 203, Chevy, Mike Goodfish
>   - Car, Raceway Park, 01/27/2015, 78 Ford Nova, Red, 02:51.22, 204, Nova, Kyle Goodfish
>   - Car, Raceway Park, 01/27/2015, 93 Chevy AstroVan, Blue, 01:46.22, 205, Chevy, Mic Rib
>   - Car, Raceway Park, 01/27/2015, 93 Escort, Blue, 02:53.22, 207, Ford, Molly George
>   - Car, Candle Wood, 02/01/2015, 77 Impala, Red, 04:20.22, 203, Chevy, Mike Goodfish
>   - Car, Candle Wood, 02/01/2015, 78 Ford Nova, Red, 04:51.22, 204, Nova, Kyle Goodfish
>   - Car, Candle Wood, 02/01/2015, 93 Chevy AstroVan, Blue, 04:46.22, 205, Chevy, Mic Rib
>   - Car, Candle Wood, 02/01/2015, 93 Escort, Blue, 03:53.22, 207, Ford, Molly George
>   - Boat, Morgo Lake, 02/02/2015, 83 Bayshore, Red, 04:20.22, 203, Chevy, Mike Goodfish
>   - Boat, Morgo Lake, 02/02/2015, 85 DoesNotFloat, Red, 04:51.22, 204, Nova, Kyle Goodfish
>   - Boat, Morgo Lake, 02/02/2015, 78 Canoe, Blue, 04:46.22, 205, Chevy, Mic Rib
>   - Boat, Morgo Lake, 02/02/2015, 01 Rocket, Blue, 03:53.22, 207, Ford, Molly George

Then in the post I could simply do something like the following:

`[ShowMe Cat=Boat Place=Raceway Park Date=01/27/2015 Sort=Time Order=Asc]`

It would then only display the following from the above data set

> - - Car, Raceway Park, 01/27/2015, 93 Chevy AstroVan, Blue, 01:46.22, 205, Chevy, Mic Rib
>   - Car, Raceway Park, 01/27/2015, 93 Escort, Blue, 02:53.22, 207, Ford, Molly George
>   - Car, Raceway Park, 01/27/2015, 78 Ford Nova, Red, 02:51.22, 204, Nova, Kyle Goodfish
>   - Car, Raceway Park, 01/27/2015, 77 Impala, Red, 03:20.22, 203, Chevy, Mike Goodfish*